# Magento - Disable Products at certain time

Tags: magento, product

In the shop I want to sell products and events as well. All events (virtual products) have the attribute `date`. When the event is over I want its status set to disabled.
How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/06/07/how-to-schedule-the-future-product-activation.html ... then you could just reverse the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [How to schedule the future product activation](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/06/07/how-to-schedule-the-future-product-activation.html) and reverse the logic to disable products.